# Passing Array Index to onClick Function ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the data from an array to onClick function using some value as reference maybe using index

here is the code

```
tempEle.push(
<tr key={set.product[i].id}>

<td className="body-sticky">
<div>
<strong>
{set.product[i] && set.product[i].name
? <a href= {set.product[i].id} onClick = {(e, id)=>alert(e.preventDefault(),id)} > 
{set.product[i].name}  
</a>
: '-'}
</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your onClick attribute to blank arrow method. This should work.

```
{set.product[i] && set.product[i].name
 ? <a href= {set.product[i].id} onClick = {()=>alert(set.product[i].id)} > 
 {set.product[i].name}
```

This will create a new method which will execute when you click on the link.

Comment: <a href= {set.product[i].id} onClick = {()=>clickHandler(e,set.product[i].id)} >  .. i would like to pass this value to handler and moreover rightnow page gets refreshed after clicking